# Good applications to develop for comparing shared vs distributed memory model?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, model, distributed, shared

I'm currently investigating the two memory models currently in use in parallel programming which are shared and distributed memory model. I know that both memory models have their own strengths/weaknesses, and one will be better over the other depending on the application. My questions are as follows:

What are some good applications for shared memory model?

What are some good applications for distributed memory model?

Comment: With respect to what programming language you are asking ?

Comment: @smilyface Java for shared memory and Erlang for distributed memory.